# Como consumir webAPI REST ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest

Bom é o seguinte, estou desenvolvendo um service Rest e uma aplicação que irá consumir esse web-service (VIA BROWSER MESMO).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No meu projeto, eu tenho o model(no caso o meu banco de dados Oracle),
meu controler ProdutosController.css que tem o método get nome do produto.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o web-service está funcionado certinho (Exemplo: foto do postman).[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Dúvida:**

**Só estou com dúvida como consumir esse web-service, ele ira voltar um json, gostaria de gerar uma view com tabela (GridView) em MVC com o nome da cada produto no caso.**

Comment: Você pode usar a classe HttpClient do c#.

Comment: Olá Maycon dei uma lida, entendi pra que serve, mas você tem alguma referencia ou Exemplo para fácil entendimento ?

Comment: Nesse artigo você verá como criar o HttpClient e pegar o resultado da chamada: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/consuming-asp-net-web-api-rest-service-in-asp-net-mvc-using-http-client/

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse link na parte do componente jqGrid.
[link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/performing-crud-operation-using-jqgrid-in-Asp-Net-mvc)

Comment: qual é a versão do asp.net e mvc que está usando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue um exemplo básico e robusto:

Primeiro crie uma ViewModel, isso não é mandatório mas é uma boa prática e no futuro vai perceber os benefícios de tal.

```
namespace Exemplo.ViewModels
{
    public class ProdutosViewModel {

        public List<string> ListaProdutos { get; set; }

        public ProdutosViewModel()
        {
            ListaProdutos = new List<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

Depois na sua `Controller`, você consulta sua API, popula a ProdutosViewModel e retorna a View

```
namespace Exemplo.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            string ApiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:53568/"; // endereço da sua api
            string MetodoPath = "Produtos/GetTodosProdutos"; //caminho do método a ser chamado

            var model = new ProdutosViewModel();
            try
            {
                var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ApiBaseUrl + MetodoPath);
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";    

                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var retorno = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(streamReader.ReadToEnd());

                    if (retorno != null)
                        model.ListaProdutos = retorno;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }


            return View(model);
        }
    }    
 }
```

Por fim na sua `View` Index, você declara a ProdutosViewModel como sua @Model e faz a exibição da lista de produtos obtida de sua API na Controller. No seu caso como queria montar uma tabela com o nome dos produtos, segue um exemplo bem básico mesmo só para demontração

```
@model Exemplo.ViewModels.ProdutosViewModel

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<div>
    @if (Model.ListaProdutos != null && Model.ListaProdutos.Count > 0)
    {
        <table>
            @foreach (var prod in Model.ListaProdutos)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.Raw(prod)</td>
                </tr>
            }

        </table>
    }
</div>
```